# How to secure credentials for CIFS volume in docker stack - secrets?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, cifs, docker-secrets

Can secrets be used to store the username and password for use in a volume definition in a stack yaml file?

If so, how?

If not, then how best to not have to include credentials in the yaml file?

For example, my stack contains sections as follows...

```yaml
networks:
  media-net:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.31.1.0/24

secrets:
  smb-user:
    external: true
    name: docker-smb-user
  smb-password:
    external: true
    name: docker-smb-password
...
volumes:
  media-movies:
    name: media-movies
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      device: "//storage.lan/media-movies"
      o: "addr=storage.lan,vers=3.0,username=/run/secrets/smb-user,password=/run/secrets/smb-password,uid=1000,gid=1000"
```

I tried using /run/secrets/smb-user etc in the options line but got an error which may or may not be related. Something like "no route to host".

Do I have both a networking and a credentials problem here? Can the overlay see the lan the hosts are on or is a separate definition required?

I specifically only use yaml files so all definitions can be maintained in a git repo.

Comment: Good question, I'd also love to know the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need for secrets. This is a named volume, meaning once it's created, it will persist until all containers using it are deleted and volume is manually removed.

If you want this information to be secret just omit it from docker-compose completely and create it manually once with:

```
docker volume create `
   --driver local `
   --opt type=cifs `
   --opt device=//storage.lan/media-movies `
   --opt o=addr=storage.lan,vers=3.0,username=foo,password=bar,uid=1000,gid=1000 `
   media-movies
```

You may want to add this to README for future reference (with blanked credentials of course). And then you don't need any volume details in your docker-compose file.

```
volumes:
  media-movies:
```

Comment: You’ve missed the point - I use docker compose and I don’t want credentials in the yaml file

Comment: @Mark I get your point, but that's I'm afraid not possible. Tmk you can't use files or placeholders in options string, therefore no secrets. I provided solution that lets you create this volume in a manner it does not need to be part of the YAML, it's a one time thing.

Comment: Ok, seems like a bit of an oversight but I’m guessing that creating the volume outside is therefore the textbook solution. Marked as solution.

Comment: If you do `docker volume inspect media-movies` you will be able to see the credentials

Comment: If I create the volume using the command, I can read the credentials back again in plain text using the 'docker volume inspect' command.

Comment: I fail to see problem with being able to display password with inspect? Question was about hiding it from yaml file that can be shared around or commited to repository. What is purpose of hiding it from an administrator? Whoever can inspect volume can also mount into it. Obscuring password while permitting access doesn't add anything into security.